# Rails json api only returning created_at and updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have opened a json API to get data on bikes. The API works fine in that it does return json, but for some reason it's only returning certain fields, namely the created_at and updated_at fields.

Here's what's in my db:

```
=> #<Bike id: 1, status: "available", location: 0, model: nil, created_at: "2015-02-04 08:21:27", updated_at: "2015-02-04 08:21:27", network_id: nil>
```

Here's what my API returns:

```
{"id":1,"created_at":"2015-02-04T08:21:27.183Z","updated_at":"2015-02-04T08:21:27.183Z"}
```

Here's my controller code:

```
before_action :set_bike, except: [:index, :create]

respond_to :json

def show
  respond_with(@bike)
end

def set_bike
  @bike = Bike.find(params[:id])
end

def bike_params
  params.require(:bike)
  .permit(:status, :model, :network => [:name], :location => [:latitude, :longitude])
end
```

My route has default to json. And in my Bike model there is no additional as_json methods. Any idea's why I'm missing 'status' and 'location'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, you can output to the console the result of your model to_json with

```
def show
  # Temporary debug, to be removed
  pp @bike.to_json

  respond_with(@bike)
end
```

And whatever will be you finding I suggest you to use `render` instead of `respond_with` to workaround your issue, like this:

```
def show
  render json: @bike
end
```

Comment: When I change to render json: @bike it returned the correct results. Anyone know why render would do this vs respond_with? shouldn't respond_with do exactly render for get requests?

Comment: As per the docs: " if the resource passed to respond_with responds to to_<format>, the method attempts to render the resource in the requested format directly". You mentioned not having any `as_json`. Do you have a `to_json` or a user.json template file? If not, then I have no idea

Comment: yea I don't have either, I guess I could make one to force it. But I just figured the default would show everything.